# Extracting the Month number from a Date... and advancing it

Tags: php

I have looked through the database of other case inquiries and find nothing central to my issue. Therefore:

```
$resultmonth1 == date("n");
if ($resultmonth1 == 12){
   $resultmonth2 = 1;
}
else {
   $resultmonth2 = $resultmonth1++;
}
```

This code generates no obvious errors or issues, except that it doesn't propagate any result to `$resultmonth2`.

What I am trying to accomplish:

I need to produce a variable that holds the number (no leading zeros) of the month following the current month. So if it is April, I need the variable to reflect May (5).

Am I missing something? Is there an easier way to do this. Preferrably in JS, but I am using PHP because I don't know any JS at all.

Answer (score 1):

You never assign anything to `$resultmonth1`:

```
$resultmonth1 == date("n");
```

Should be:

```
$resultmonth1 = date("n");
```

Otherwise you're doing a comparison.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't catch that! I should have known. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a basic `==` and `=` issue but i still prefer working with date in the manner

```
$date = new DateTime();
$resultmonth1 = $date->format("n");

$date->modify("next month");
$resultmonth2 = $date->format("n");

var_dump($resultmonth1,$resultmonth2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `==` with `=` in this line.

```
$resultmonth1 = date("n");
```